# Hunter's Aim for Alchemist

Tags: feats, multi-classing, pathfinder-2e

Is there any way to take the [Hunter's Aim](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=496) Ranger feat on or before level 2 with an Alchemist?

With the usual route (Ranger Dedication then Basic Hunter's Trick) you have to wait until level 4.

---

reason:
I could not find good 2nd level class feats for a Bomber, but there are great ones for level 4.

Comment: Smoke bomb seems useful, as does whichever of Far Lobber and Quick Bomber you didn't pick up at level 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### There is no way

You could get Ranger Dedication before 2, meaning you "could" take Hunter's Aim at two, but the [Dedication Feats](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=723) that would allow you to take it have a required level of 4 or higher.

Additionally, there is [no way](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=725) to take multiclass feats that are 'caught up' to your character level. They *seem to be* designed to ensure that multiclassing does not encroach on the classes' viability as a main class.